# Append continuous data to the same row using CSV lib, in Python

Tags: python, csv

Here is my code:

```
import csv

with open(outputfile, 'a') as csvfile:
    filewrite = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    filewrite.writerow([hostname])
    if (CiscoSyslog == 0):
        filewrite.writerow(['Syslog'])
    if (CiscoSNMP == 0):
        filewrite.writerow(['SNMP'])
```

At the moment, it outputs data in a new row, as it finds it. Basically, the ultimate goal is to generate a CSV file with bunch of hostnames that are missing Syslog and/or SNMP configuration. The way I want it to look in the end is, for example:

```
router1,Syslog
router2,SNMP
router3,Syslog,SNMP
```

As you can see, at the begging I have the file open and it prints out the hostname, then, my goal at the moment is: I would like to keep the row "open", so I can keep appending more data as the "if" statements keep finding a match. And ultimately it produces something similar to the example I have shown above.

I tried researching on this forum, and other forums, but I keep finding examples of how to append to a new row in CSV, or I keep finding comments by random people, how CSV library does not support adding a new column.

Some help would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to construct your row entirely before trying to write it. Try this:

```
import csv

with open(outputfile, 'a') as csvfile:
    filewrite = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    row = [hostname]
    if (CiscoSyslog == 0):
        row.append('Syslog')
    if (CiscoSNMP == 0):
        row.append('SNMP')
    filewrite.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked, the way I desired it.

Comment: If it worked for you, would you mind marking this answer as the solution?

Comment: Oh, ya, no problem, sorry about that. Done! :)

Answer (score 0):

The argument of cvs.writerow is a list, the list of cells.
So you can build the row before outputing it, like :

```
row=[]
if something:
    row.append("cell1valA")
else:
    row.append("cell1valB")
row.append("cell2")
row.append("cell3")
row.append("cell4")
filewrite.writerow(row)
```