# Sort data in CSV file to which column it belongs to using CSV lib in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, csv

Previously I have opened this topic: [Append continuous data to the same row using CSV lib, in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40753616/append-continuous-data-to-the-same-row-using-csv-lib-in-python)

Which someone suggested a solution for me, that worked beautifully. The code suggested that it worked is as follows:

```
import csv

filewrite.writerow(['Hostname', 'Config-Error', 'Config-Error'])
with open(outputfile, 'a') as csvfile:
    filewrite = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    row = [hostname]
    if (CiscoSyslog == 0):
        row.append('Syslog')
    if (CiscoSNMP == 0):
        row.append('SNMP')
    filewrite.writerow(row)
```

The output comes as desired:

```
hostname,Config-Error,Config-Error
router1,Syslog
router2,SNMP
router3,Syslog,SNMP
```

Now, my next question is, how would you take that appended data to one row, and sort it to belong to a certain column? For example, instead of having two columns on top saying "Config-Error", I would like on one column at the top to say SyslogError, and the other SNMPError, so it would look something like:

```
hostname,SyslogError,SNMPError
router1,Syslog, ,
router2, ,SNMP
router3,Syslog,SNMP
```

My end goal is to match the error that will find in a configuration, append it to a CSV file, and sort it on the proper column. I wasn't even sure how to "google search" this, so I decided to pose the question here.

I am still a little new to python, but learning has been fun so far.

Thank you in advance!

Viktor

Comment: I figured it out... I will share my answer once I finish testing it... Thanks for everyone's time, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was so simple, it was "staring" in my eyes. :)

Basically, I got rid of the "if" statements, where data is appended under a row. I also included a little more of my code, so it fully makes sense, in case someone is looking for an answer to a similar puzzle.

So... I setup flags to begin with as "Yes" (as you can see in the code). They all remain set to "Yes", should some of the statements for each variable (Syslog, SNMP and Tacacs) are not found. I perform a "re.search" method, and if it finds the statement under a configuration, it flags it as "No", thus it does not need to be printed to the output file (or in other words, the configuration is present, so there is "No" config error). For any of the flags still remaining as "Yes", I print out each "flag" (variable in this case) **in order**, each time, that way it goes in the **proper column**.

Here is the code:

```
import csv
import re


Syslog = 'logging 1.1.1.1'
SNMP = 'snmp-server host 2.2.2.2'
Tacacs = 'tacacs-server host 3.3.3.3'

filewrite.writerow(['Hostname', 'SyslogError', 'SNMPError', 'TacacsError'])

with open(file, 'r') as inFile:
    SyslogFlag = 'Yes'
    SNMPFlag = 'Yes'
    TacacsFlag = 'Yes'

    for line in inFile:
        if re.search(Syslog, line):
            SyslogFlag = 'No'
        if re.search(SNMP, line):
            SNMPFlag = 'No'
        if re.search(Tacacs, line):
            TacacsFlag = 'No'

    if (SyslogFlag == 'No') and (SNMPFlag == 'No') and (TacacsFlag == 'No'):
        print "No Config errors"
    else:
        with open(outputfile, 'a') as csvfile:
            filewrite = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            row = [hostname]
            row.append(SyslogFlag)
            row.append(SNMPFlag)
            row.append(TacacsFlag)
            filewrite.writerow(row)
```

Here is the output:

```
Hostname,SyslogError,SNMPError,TacacsError
router1,Yes,No,No
router2,No,Yes,No
router3,Yes,Yes,No
```